# Spring Integration Flow route based on file name

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a requirement to unzip and file and process its contents. Inside the zip file, there could be two types of file individual or firm. That can be distinguished by file name. After processing of all files, it should call another program module, also archive the processed file in a different location. Would like use Spring integration for the same. I am trying to achieve this by the following code, but it is creating problem while routing based on file name. I am using JDK 8, Spring 5

```
.<File, Boolean>route(new Function<File, Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public Boolean apply(File f) {
                        return f.getName().contains("individual");
                    }
                }, m -> m
                        .subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf.gateway(individualProcessor()))
                        .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.gateway(firmProcessor()))
                )
```

Exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [interface java.util.function.Function] for method match: [public default <V> java.util.function.Function<V, R> java.util.function.Function.compose(java.util.function.Function<? super V, ? extends T>), public static <T> java.util.function.Function<T, T> java.util.function.Function.identity(), public java.lang.Boolean com.xxx.thirdpatysystem.config.IntegrationConfig$1.apply(java.io.File)]
    at org.springframework.util.Assert.isNull(Assert.java:155) ~[spring-core-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.findHandlerMethodsForTarget(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:843) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:362) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:231) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.util.MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.<init>(MessagingMethodInvokerHelper.java:225) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.<init>(MethodInvokingMessageProcessor.java:60) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.router.MethodInvokingRouter.<init>(MethodInvokingRouter.java:46) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.route(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:1922) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.route(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:1895) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
```

even I have tried below

```
.<File, Boolean>route(f -> f.getName().contains("individual"), m -> m
                        .subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf.gateway(individualProcessor()))
                        .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.gateway(firmProcessor()))
                )
```

Exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'thirdpatysystemFlow' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:579) ~[spring-beans-5.0.4.RELEASE.jar:5.0.4.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: null
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow.configure(StandardIntegrationFlow.java:89) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.gateway(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:2172) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlowDefinition.gateway(IntegrationFlowDefinition.java:2151) ~[spring-integration-core-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
```

Entire code snippet is below

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.function.Function;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.config.EnableIntegration;
import org.springframework.integration.core.MessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.Pollers;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.channel.MessageChannels;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileReadingMessageSource;
import org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.AcceptOnceFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.ChainFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.file.filters.RegexPatternFileListFilter;
import org.springframework.integration.zip.splitter.UnZipResultSplitter;
import org.springframework.integration.zip.transformer.UnZipTransformer;
import org.springframework.integration.zip.transformer.ZipResultType;
import org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandler;
import org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor;

/**
 * @author dpoddar
 *
 */
@Configuration
@EnableIntegration
public class IntegrationConfig {

    @Value("${input.directory}")
    private String inputDir;

    @Value("${outputDir.directory}")
    private String outputDir;

    @Value("${input.scan.frequency: 100}")
    private long scanFrequency;

    @Bean
    public MessageSource<File> inputFileSource() {
        FileReadingMessageSource src = new FileReadingMessageSource();

        src.setDirectory(new File(inputDir));
        src.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);

        ChainFileListFilter<File> chainFileListFilter = new ChainFileListFilter<>();
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new AcceptOnceFileListFilter<>() );
        chainFileListFilter.addFilter(new RegexPatternFileListFilter("(?i)^.+\\.zip$"));
        src.setFilter(chainFileListFilter);
        return src;
    }

    @Bean
    public UnZipTransformer unZipTransformer() {
        UnZipTransformer unZipTransformer = new UnZipTransformer();
        unZipTransformer.setExpectSingleResult(false);
        unZipTransformer.setZipResultType(ZipResultType.FILE);
        //unZipTransformer.setWorkDirectory(new File("/usr/tmp/uncompress"));
        unZipTransformer.setDeleteFiles(true);
        return unZipTransformer;
    }

    @Bean
    public UnZipResultSplitter splitter() {
        UnZipResultSplitter splitter = new UnZipResultSplitter();

        return splitter;
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel outputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageHandler fileOutboundChannelAdapter() {
        FileWritingMessageHandler adapter = new FileWritingMessageHandler(new File(outputDir));
        adapter.setDeleteSourceFiles(true);
        adapter.setAutoCreateDirectory(true);
        adapter.setExpectReply(false);
        return adapter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskExecutor taskExecutor() {
        ThreadPoolTaskExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolTaskExecutor();
        executor.setCorePoolSize(5);
        executor.setMaxPoolSize(10);
        executor.setQueueCapacity(25);
        return executor;
    }

    @Autowired
    DirectChannel outputChannel;

    @Autowired
    MessageHandler fileOutboundChannelAdapter;

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow individualProcessor() {
        return flow -> flow.handle("thirdpatysystemprocessor","processfile").channel(outputChannel).handle(fileOutboundChannelAdapter);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow firmProcessor() {
        return flow -> flow.handle("thirdpatysystemprocessor","processfile").channel(outputChannel).handle(fileOutboundChannelAdapter);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow thirdpatysystemAgentDemographicFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(inputFileSource(), spec -> spec.poller(Pollers.fixedDelay(scanFrequency,TimeUnit.SECONDS)))
                .transform(unZipTransformer())
                .split(splitter())
                .channel(MessageChannels.executor(taskExecutor()))
                .<File, Boolean>route(new Function<File, Boolean>() {

                    @Override
                    public Boolean apply(File f) {
                        return f.getName().contains("individual");
                    }
                }, m -> m
                        .subFlowMapping(true, sf -> sf.gateway(individualProcessor()))
                        .subFlowMapping(false, sf -> sf.gateway(firmProcessor()))
                )
                .aggregate()
                /*.handle("thirdpatysystemprocessor","processfile")
                .channel(outputChannel())
                .handle(fileOutboundChannelAdapter())*/
                .get()
                ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Found ambiguous parameter type [interface java.util.function.Function]` has been fixed in the Spring Integration `5.0.5`: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4456. So, now with an explicit `Function` impl we do this:

```
MethodInvokingRouter methodInvokingRouter = isLambda(router)
            ? new MethodInvokingRouter(new LambdaMessageProcessor(router, payloadType))
            : new MethodInvokingRouter(router, ClassUtils.FUNCTION_APPLY_METHOD);
```

We explicitly point to the `apply()` method.

The re-use of existing `IntegrationFlow` beans in the sub-flows (`gateway()`) has been fixed in version `5.0.4`: https://jira.spring.io/browse/INT-4434

So, what you need is just to upgrade your project to the latest dependencies. In particular Spring Integration `5.0.7`: https://spring.io/projects/spring-integration#learn

Comment: Thanks changing spring boot to 2.0.4 solved the issue